# Website is not compatible in a AOL Browser

Tags: html, coding-style, cross-browser

I built a website and it looks fine in browsers like IE and Firefox, but the background does not show up in an AOL browser. Is there a special way I need to code the background image or any tips on how to make it compatible?

Comment: > implying anyone actually uses AOL browser and AOL browser doesn't use the IE engine

Comment: Does anyone actually use AOL browser? I feel sorry for them..

Comment: Do you know what versions of the AOL software show the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, AOL *Browser* has not existed since July 2005... However I will take *AOL Browser* to mean *AOL Explorer* for this answer, which it has been named since 2005. If I am wrong... Update your web browser (Get rid of AOL and use another mainstream one)

AOL Explorer was built on the Trident HTML renderer, AKA MSHTML... Also implemented in (You guessed it) Internet Explorer.

If you are using AOL Browser, upgrade IE to get a newer version of Trident.

Secondly, you need to include your source code so we can see if you are using Trident version compatible HTML.

So in short, provide us with the source code of your `<head>` tag so we can make sure you are doing it properly and upgrade IE to the newest version (or at least version 6).

Comment: and by "or at least version 6" @JD means get IE9 or better yet... Chrome.